# mongofiles : whats the usage of --collection option?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I can use "-d" option to put files into a database.

```
mongofiles  -d test put file.txt
```

It worked as expected.I also found out there was collection option. Whats this option for and How to use it? I can't get more info from man page or its help.

EDIT : 
From here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification . I believe there will be two collection will be created named "files" and "chunk" which will contain metadata of file and its actually data. When  I simply use -d option alone.  I can see these collections under "test" db. So now ,when i use the option -c does that collection will stores what?

Comment: Which version of mongofiles and GridFS in general do you use?

Comment: My mongodb version is  v2.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/index.html#gridfs.GridFS 
`collection` specifies the root collection to use.

I believe that the expected behaviour is totally internal, i.e. the default collection where the files are stored is `'fs'`. You can replace that to have a custom collection name.

Comment: I tried something like mongofiles -d dbname -c collection-name put file.txt. Whats the expected behavior here?.

Comment: I tried the following created a new db named test1 and put a file into it(with -d option). Now I did a show collections. I can see fs.files and fs.chunks. Now I created another db named test2 and put a file into it (with -d -c options).when I do show collections. I can only see fs.files and fs.chunks but not the collection name passed with -c option. Please let me know,I missed something.

Comment: Have you tried using python driver directly. It might be that `mongofiles` don't interpret `-c` options correctly.

Answer (score 2):

refer [Using mongofiles with GridFS in a meteor app - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172205/using-mongofiles-with-gridfs-in-a-meteor-app), the `collection` option actually is `prefix` -> `mongofiles --help` show this:

```
--prefix=<prefix>     GridFS prefix to use (default is 'fs') (default: fs)
```

my example:

```
mongofiles -d storybook --prefix audio -t audio/mpeg -l=5bd7bd3abfaa44fe2c73754d.mp3 put 5bd7bd3abfaa44fe2c73754d.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be in new releases of mongo **only use the fs collection to store files**. I could not find the [technical reason](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-97).

Instead of separating files into collections, 
[Mike O'Brien](https://www.mongodb.com/profile/mike-obrien) suggests using prefixes. For example:

```
mongofiles put /tmp/testfile --prefix "customer1"
```